# Amcharts Not displaying all graphs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, amcharts

I have a tabbed interface (jQuery UI) where I can dynamically add tabs to show graphs.
In a certain use-case, I have to render multiple pie charts (am using amcharts) inside the same tab. While this works on a standalone page (no tabbed UI or jQuery script), it fails when I try to implement it: only the last pie chart is displayed and the other div placeholders (for the preceding pies) are empty.

Please help... going crazy here trying to figure this one out!

PS: I have also tried out invalidateSize() for each of the pies, but it seems to work only for the last pie-chart.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution instead of `invalidateSize` (does not always work when you have severals amcharts in a tab); just play with show (tested on IE7, Chrome & FF).

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
$('#tabs-1').show(); /* I have 5 amcharts here */
$('#tabs-2').show(); /* I have 15 amcharts here */
$('#tabs-3').show(); /* I have 2 amcharts here */
/* +++ */ 
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#tabs-2').hide();
    $('#tabs-3').hide();
}, 1000 );
```